# Rails google map check if point lies within certain radius

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps, geolocation

I have a user model which stores the lat and log of a user in latitude and longitude field.

Now I have a arbitrary point (lat and longitude).

Now what is the best way to find all the users which lies in the radius of 10kms of that arbitrary point.

Does geocoder gem does it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yup Geocoder have this feature ie to check if it any point (latitude, longitude) lies within certain radius  of certian point.

Lets say an arbitrary object of model **X** with fields **latitude** = x and **longitude** = y be **obj**

Now to find any similar object within **m miles** radius from **obj** we can do

```
   obj.nearbys(m)
```

This query will return all X's which lies within x miles radius form obj

Answer (score 1):

Geocoder does seem to have [what you need](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder#distance-and-bearing). You could also [roll your own](http://vinsol.com/blog/2011/08/30/geoproximity-search-with-mysql/).